# how to resolve scene view not working properly with 3D URP in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

When i open my project, my scene view seems to be not rendering correctly, although it's working on game space, does anyone would know why?

[Scene not working properly in unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7TAD.png)

[Game workig properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGQhP.png)

Comment: does your machine meet the required specs for unity?

Comment: @BugFinder yes, it does, although i'm using linux

Comment: Are there some custom RendererFeatures active?